# VBA Proxy auto-configuration for http requests

Tags: vba, excel

I need to build a client for a web api in VBA and it needs to work behind a proxy (with authentication). I've been looking at the  WinHttp.WinHttpRequest and MSXML2.XMLHTTP/ServerXMLHTTP classes. It turns out that:

- XMLHTTP automatically detects proxy settings provided through a *proxy.pac* file (good)
- WinHttpRequest doesn't (bad)

However, on the other hand:

- XMLHTTP automatically follows redirects, and there's [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594234/can-you-detect-a-301-redirect-with-microsoft-xmlhttp-object) of disabling this behaviour (bad)
- WinHttpRequest doesn't (good)

Since I'd like to be able to have my cake and eat it, is there a way to get automatic proxy configuration for a component such as WinHttpRequest that doesn't follow redirects blindly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VBA-Web project might help you with your pastry eating problem.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

I guess what you wish to do would go something like:

```
Dim client As New WebClient
With client
    .BaseUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    .ProxyUsername = <user>
    .ProxyPassword = <password>
    .EnableAutoProxy = True
End With

Dim request As New WebRequest
With request
    .Method = WebMethod.HttpGet
    .Format = WebFormat.PlainText
End With

Dim response As WebResponse
Set response = client.Execute(request)
```