# Question on authenticating thru winhttp secure website

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, winhttp

I have read quite a few threads on the subject but need a push in the right direction. I'm attempting to download pdfs from a secure website. I can login with InternetExplorer using vba automation & navigate the web page successfully. This is a requirement because I need to get my list of files & build the URL's. That I can do.

I'm trying to download the files with winnhttp 5.1 & the download code works, if I manually feed it the 6 cookies from fiddler. Here is where I'm stuck on what I think might not be the too hard part. To date I've gotten cookies in two batches. From document.cookie gets me 4, including an authToken. From my winhttp stream I get two http only cookies including an ASP Session id, but i realized eventually that these two are really a different "session". The two http cookies from what i understand will never be exposed within document.cookie. But since I get them in my winhttp stream I think I'm ok there.

```
This is my first call that nets me the two http cookies


WinHttpReq.Open "POST", strUrl, False
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://atlasbridge.com/default.aspx"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "X-MicrosoftAjax", "Delta=true"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Host", "atlasbridge.com"
 WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
 'uname & password are established earlier in the code & are the correct values
WinHttpReq.SetCredentials UName, Pword, 0
WinHttpReq.Send
```

I can parse cookies I get back I'm sure. I just need to return the first 4 cookies including the authentication token. I think I'll need to send a few request to the website & then to the reports page (one cookie changes from home page to reports) but since I need user name and password to authenticate how to do i do that in winhttp (or do I use another mwthod). I can login into to the page but that does't get me the http only cookies so I need to authenticate this other way (I assume).

p.s. thread as I captured and parsed cookies and got to this point. [How to download file from secure website with WinHTTPRequest.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223572/how-to-download-file-from-secure-website-with-winhttprequest-5-1?noredirect=1#comment95285752_54223572)

I've updated the code in the question, but I'm still not sure how to authenticate with winhttp.

the response I get back is(where the two cookies I get, but not the other 4 I need:
STATUSCODE:200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2019 19:45:23 GMT
Content-Length: 2033
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=xxxxxxxxxx; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: NSC_bumbtcsjehf.dpn_TTM_443xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Version=1;Max-Age=2400;path=/;secure;httponly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Cteonnt-Length: 4489

Also using fiddler I see in text view:
ScriptManager1=UpdatePanel1%7CcmdLogin&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=6mcXww3ohBjEvWka9jUmRYsQUSnYbYvMovHGR6aC%2BUr5hum9HsnxvbQYFOUuvkWDHWcIz5hftDgGPlmEOUJUqC11qvzFgYZh24%2FDDMPA6e0A7AeaAWc0mRfrrbYjbUeUvPE38g%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=CA0B0334&__EVENTVALIDATION=5XlJ8vCmmt4cJhBg5XYEHmCDfdimT2%2FjpQGEczZ7weYVU3RB%2BZzR7pLr2RN%2F6ooiMEnAs6DMB26%2F3fXnRVrNpvT6Qaj62mNxwriRgMUs2WY5e538aZbVQ1dXouLb1cAAnPt%2BOfWGWfumid1o3Eg%2FYOyuvRA%3D&txtUserName=MyUsernamevaluehere&txtPassword=MyPasswordvaluehere&__ASYNCPOST=true&cmdLogin.x=33&cmdLogin.y=15.569999694824218

Fiddler is showing the first "Post" request is XMLHttpRequest. I still am only getting 2 cookies(the same 2).