# Connecting to Web API with Cookie Authentication and CSRF Token

Tags: vba, session-cookies, csrf, msxml, api-authorization

***UPDATE AT THE END**

I need help with using an API to authenticate into https://connect.garmin.com/signin/.
I am using VBA and Power Query to automate the collecting of workout data from my Garmin account. As far as I can tell, the website uses cookie based authentication and a CSRF token.

I am testing my API calls in Postman, building the authentication request in VBA, and performing data collection in Power Query with the authenticated cookies. *(I would use Power Query for the whole project, but it is not able to return the response headers/authenticated cookies)*

I am trying to replicate the browser actions by collecting the cookies from response headers and CSRF token from the HTML body before making the authentication POST request, but I am not having much success. When I try to authenticate using this method the response status is 200 and response body is the login page with a "*Something went wrong*" message.

I have tried to follow OmegaStripes answer from this question to get a handle on the cookies,
[How to set and get JSESSIONID cookie in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709562/how-to-set-and-get-jsessionid-cookie-in-vba)

Is there a special way to handle CSRF tokens in Postman or VBA `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`? Is there something I am fundamentally not understanding about cookie authentication?

If you need any further info from me, please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My modified version of OmegaStripes code is below,

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetCookie()

    Dim sUrl, sRespHeaders, sRespText, aSetHeaders, aList, aSetBody, sCSRFToken, sBody

    sBody = "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&embed=false&_csrf="

    ' get cookie 1
    sUrl = "https://connect.garmin.com/signin/"
    XmlHttpRequest "GET", sUrl, Array(), "", sRespHeaders, sRespText
    ParseResponse "^Set-(Cookie): (\S*?=\S*?);[\s\S]*?$", sRespHeaders, aSetHeaders

    ' get cookie 2 and CSRF Token
    sUrl = "https://sso.garmin.com/sso/signin?service=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&webhost=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&source=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fsignin%2F&redirectAfterAccountLoginUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&redirectAfterAccountCreationUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&gauthHost=https%3A%2F%2Fsso.garmin.com%2Fsso&locale=en_US&id=gauth-widget&cssUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fgauth-custom-v1.2-min.css&privacyStatementUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.garmin.com%2Fen-US%2Fprivacy%2Fconnect%2F&clientId=GarminConnect&displayNameShown=false&consumeServiceTicket=false&generateExtraServiceTicket=true&generateTwoExtraServiceTickets=false&generateNoServiceTicket=false&globalOptInShown=true&globalOptInChecked=false&connectLegalTerms=true&locationPromptShown=true&showPassword=true"
    XmlHttpRequest "GET", sUrl, aSetHeaders, "", sRespHeaders, sRespText
    ' parse project names
    ParseResponse "^Set-(Cookie): (\S*?=\S*?);[\s\S]*?$", sRespHeaders, aSetHeaders
    sCSRFToken = GetCSRFToken("name=" & Chr(34) & "_csrf" & Chr(34) & " value=" & Chr(34), sRespText)

    ' get authenticated cookies
    sUrl = "https://sso.garmin.com/sso/signin?service=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&webhost=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&source=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fsignin%2F&redirectAfterAccountLoginUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&redirectAfterAccountCreationUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fmodern%2F&gauthHost=https%3A%2F%2Fsso.garmin.com%2Fsso&locale=en_US&id=gauth-widget&cssUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fconnect.garmin.com%2Fgauth-custom-v1.2-min.css&privacyStatementUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.garmin.com%2Fen-US%2Fprivacy%2Fconnect%2F&clientId=GarminConnect&displayNameShown=false&consumeServiceTicket=false&generateExtraServiceTicket=true&generateTwoExtraServiceTickets=false&generateNoServiceTicket=false&globalOptInShown=true&globalOptInChecked=false&connectLegalTerms=true&locationPromptShown=true&showPassword=true"
    XmlHttpRequest "POST", sUrl, aSetHeaders, sBody & sCSRFToken, sRespHeaders, sRespText
    ' parse project names
    ParseResponse "^Set-(Cookie): (\S*?=\S*?);[\s\S]*?$", sRespHeaders, aSetHeaders

End Sub

Sub XmlHttpRequest(sMethod, sUrl, aSetHeaders, sPayload, sRespHeaders, sRespText)
    Dim aHeader
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        '.SetOption 2, 13056 ' SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open sMethod, sUrl, False
        For Each aHeader In aSetHeaders
            .SetRequestHeader aHeader(0), aHeader(1)
        Next
        .Send (sPayload)
        sRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        sRespText = .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

Sub ParseResponse(sPattern, sResponse, aData)
    Dim oMatch, aTmp, sSubMatch
    If IsEmpty(aData) Then
        aData = Array()
    End If
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sResponse)
            If oMatch.SubMatches.Count = 1 Then
                PushItem aData, oMatch.SubMatches(0)
            Else
                aTmp = Array()
                For Each sSubMatch In oMatch.SubMatches
                    PushItem aTmp, sSubMatch
                Next
                PushItem aData, aTmp
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetCSRFToken(sPattern, sResponse)
    Dim lStart, lLength, sSubMatch

    lStart = InStr(1, sResponse, sPattern) + Len(sPattern)
    lLength = InStr(lStart, sResponse, Chr(34)) - lStart
    GetCSRFToken = Mid(sResponse, lStart, lLength)

End Function

Sub PushItem(aList, vItem)
    ReDim Preserve aList(UBound(aList) + 1)
    aList(UBound(aList)) = vItem
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT**

I have changed approach to creating an instance of Internet Explorer, and automating the log in process. Not ideal, but I am able to sign in successfully. My issue now is I am not able to retrieve the HttpOnly Cookies required to maintain the logged in session using,

`getCookie = objIE.document.Cookie`

I have tried another of OmegaStripes answers (coincidentally) [Retrieve ALL cookies from Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726408/retrieve-all-cookies-from-internet-explorer) but was unsuccessful.

Any suggestions on how to get this working with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, an IE instance, or any other method would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to make make request with redirection disabled to retrieve the token and cookies, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102412/2165759).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @omegastripes , I will give this a go.

Comment: @omegastripes the redirection disabled didn't seem to work.
I'm starting to think the issue may be that each request is recalculating the csrf token. Is that possible? Is there a way to maintain an open connection to simulate the browser with MSXML calls?

Comment: You can see in browser developer tools on network tab that the website isn't using keep-alive, and token isn't changed. Inspecting requests there I also noticed there are some other requests logged, missing them in the VBA code might affect the login process.

Comment: You re-create the HTTP client every time you make a request. If you're using the same client instance for all your requests, then the cookies will be remembered and you don't need to parse the headers. Try `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` if it's not working.